# Script not working. Worked before

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know much js but I created a simple script to allow visiting a page only from a certain page, here is the code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
if (document.referrer == "example111/index.html")
{
window.history.go(0);
}
else
{
window.location = "index.html";
}
</script>
```

Now the problem with this is that i tried it first on a dummy website, and it worked, but now that I ported it into another website, it doesn't work, It either just redirects to "index.html"; even when viewed from the page I want it to work with, and also if accessed directly, what is its problem?

Comment: Check the value of [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.referrer), if you're comparing against wrong string. Also notice, that you may get an empty string from `referrer`. What is the idea of `history.go(0)`?

Comment: @Teemu I did, but it is correct. I've tried "sitename.com/index.html" as well as just "index.html".
Both worked on the dummy website, but now, both produce the same results.
What do you mean an empty string, it should report the page its linked to right?

Comment: What is the idea of `history.go(0)`? Reloading page would change the value of `referrer`.

Comment: @Teemu I've tried it without the code (using alert('')) but still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Syntax

```
string = document.referrer;
```

Notes

The value is an empty string if the user navigated to the page directly (not through a link, but, for example, via a bookmark). Since this property returns only a string, it does not give you DOM access to the referring page.

> TRY this is it working

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
if (document.referrer.indexOf('index.html') == -1) {
alert("Access Violation");
top.location="http://www.yahoo.com";
}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't understand much of what you said, but this is what I want, if the user goes to the page directly or through a bookmark, I don't want him to see the page, I only want the page to be visible if navigated through the link on my page.

Comment: @user3514931 Then you should use `if (document.referrer.split('/')[2] == "YOUR DOMAIN NAME")`

Comment: go(0) will work only when you have already browsed a page and navigate through any link or button

Comment: @ArjunChaudhary The second script is working, but if the page is accessed directly, It shows the "Access Violation box" but it you click OK, there is a split second where all the information is visible before the box comes back up again.

Comment: window.location = "index.html"; use this instead of alert box

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you compare `referrer` to a correct string (partial match is not enough), then try this:

```
if (document.referrer !== "example111/index.html") {
    window.location.href = "index.html";
}
```

`window.history.go(0)` reloads your page, which changes the value of [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.referrer). Then on refresh, `else` does its job.